# How to extract specific kind of links from excel cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Okay so i think i have hit a dead end with my excel skills. I have tried a lot of things and different formulas but no results.  Looking for help here .

Problem: So we have this excel sheet which has two columns

Id : which contains the in the format KMID-XXXXXX
Related Links: which contain links in the following manner.

Title1, Link1, Title 2, Link2,Title3 Link3.....

The links and title are seperated by comma and every links belongs to different internal webpage of external links.

Ask: I want to fetch a specific kind of links i.e something based on the logic that if string contains KMID links then take that particular link and extract it to third custom coloum

How do i do that?

I have tried power queries, text to column with , separator as well but there are around 20 -25 links at the highest

Comment: Adding sample data and desired outcome would be helpful.

Comment: Will be easier if you have Excel O365 version, thus having access to the new text handling functions.  Are you an O365 customer?

Comment: The latest version of Excel can achieve this function.